# Setting and using a variable in a MySQL WHERE

Tags: mysql

If I do the following query on MySQL 5.7.16, then the resultset contains one row with the value `2`, which is expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 as x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS t
WHERE ( 2 IS NULL OR t.x = 2 )
;
-- Resultset: 1 row, x = 2
```

Now, I would like to use this logic in a prepared statement, like `? IS NULL OR t.x = ?`. So you see that the same parameter appears twice. Hence, I applied an advice I found on SO (I don't remember the exact location): put the parameter in a MySQL session variable, and use it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 as x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS t
WHERE ( (@x := 2) IS NULL OR t.x = @x )
;
-- Resultset: 0 row
```

But this fails: no row is returned. When I also select the `@x` variable, in order to see what's going on, I get a `NULL` value for `@x`:

```
SELECT @x
FROM (SELECT 1 as x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS t
WHERE ( (@x := 2) IS NULL OR t.x = 2 )
;
-- Resultset: 1 row, @x = NULL
```

So it seems that the variable is not set when put in the `WHERE`? What is going on?

I could make an `INNER JOIN (SELECT 2 AS x) AS params` and use `params.x` inside the `WHERE`, but I would like to understand what's happening in that `WHERE ( (@x = 2) IS NULL OR t.x = @x )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that the order of execution inside `WHERE` is *arbitrary*. This means that using

```
(@x := 2) IS NULL OR t.x = 2
```

there is no way to guarantee that `@x := 2` will be executed first.

To correctly initialize the variable use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 as x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x := 2) AS v
WHERE ( @x IS NULL OR t.x = @x )
```